# When to pass a CancellationToken to a Controller Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cancellation-token

According to [Scalability in ASP.NET web APIs with Cancellation Tokens](https://www.kzsoftworks.com/blog/asp-net-scalability-cancellation-tokens/), CancellationTokens should be used only for HTTP GET Requests:

> Requests that can have side effects, such as creating, updating, or deleting data, should also be left as they are, because there is a real risk of compromising data integrity of the system if the request is interrupted at the wrong moment, especially if there are multiple internal steps to the operation. That leaves us only with nullipotent requests, that is, those that only fetch data but don’t modify anything after they finish, metrics and logs notwithstanding. In other words, if implemented correctly, **HTTP GET requests**.

Andrew Lock is of the same opinion in his blog post [Using CancellationTokens in ASP.NET Core MVC controllers](https://andrewlock.net/using-cancellationtokens-in-asp-net-core-mvc-controllers/):

> If the request modifies state, then you may not want to halt execution mid-way through a method. On the other hand, if the request has no side-effects, then you probably want to stop the (presumably expensive) action as soon as you can.

On the other hand, according to [Using a CancellationToken in .NET Core Web API](https://danielledevblog.medium.com/using-a-cancellationtoken-in-net-core-web-api-9779c39596d5), passing CancellationTokens also to POST / PUT / DELETE requests is encouraged:

> There are many advantages which include [...] avoiding duplication of records when creating, updating or deleting.

I remember that in several .NET web applications I used to work on in past, the CancellationToken was passed as parameter to all actions of GET / POST / PUT / DELETE requests in the Controllers.

Who of the two sources mentioned above is right resp. which is the best practice to adopt? Personally, I think that adding a CancellationToken to POST, PUT and DELETE requests can become problematic as soon as more than 1 database table / 1 file / etc. are involved in the creation / update / deletion of data, since this could lead to inconsistencies. What's your opinion about it?

Comment: Always use a cancellation token.  If you are using transactions correctly, you won't get partial records in your database.  If your repository isn't using using a unit of work pattern , then it's time to make it so.

Comment: @Neil You still need idempotent requests, otherwise weird stuff is going to happen to the client (obviously cannot affect the DB).